# Cant pick an object on bevel path curve menu

Tags: objects, error

I was trying to do a stylizied hair but couldnt do it, so i opened a new file and try it there, it was also not working, what can i do?[image: On the obecjt list you can see that nothing even shows up, on the other file with much more obecjts was the same]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over the Object dropdown list, you will notice that a tooltip pops up saying that you have to pick a [Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/index.html) object. You only have 1 curve object which is currently selected, and ofcourse you cannot use the same curve object as the one you are selecting. So you have to create another curve object. In the below example, notice that I have an Arc curve, in addition to the selected NurbsCurve object, that I can select from the list.

[image]

Comment: sorry forgot to erase the scribble over the end mapping thing. ignore that.

Comment: right, thank you so much, but i have to choose the circle to make the path get it's shape, if you look for stylized hair tutorials you will see that it should be possible to select a circle for the path to follow, yet i cant. But weird that it says only curve objects, im curious now, because i have done this before and it worked. really odd

Comment: wait, so i a just add a curve circle and it works, wow sorry for the slow realization lol